# Retrieve video ids from playlist id - youtube api v3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am currently working with youtube api v3. I am trying to retrieve `video ids` from a particular playlist. I have search through the documentation but can’t find an example that references that or something similar.  I am using this repo from [GITHUB](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api). How can I retrieve `video ids` from a given `playlist id`?

Here is a snippet but it only yields general information of the playlist:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Madcoda\Youtube;

$youtube = new Youtube(array('key' => '<API KEY>'));

// Return a std PHP object
$playlist = $youtube->getPlaylistById('PL590L5WQmH8fJ54F369BLDSqIwcs-TCfs');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($playlist);
echo "</pre>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can !

With the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) with the ressource [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

Use this parameters to get the video ID of a playlist :

```
part: 'contentDetails'
playlistId: 'PL590L5WQmH8fJ54F369BLDSqIwcs-TCfs'
```

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=PL590L5WQmH8fJ54F369BLDSqIwcs-TCfs&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The  output :

```
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/OCpNe6AE7ww8_WCYOw2M6axwxAY\"",
   "id": "PLDWb5NF1kx1qB7HgQ2tJKvLCsn0D34rFYWn3o4SsrJrU",
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "Lv-sY_z8MNs"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/Qvv0GzRVKvhc4LANFBV171hvlJI\"",
   "id": "PLDWb5NF1kx1qB7HgQ2tJKvAZrOtpGhFVaTYQJQCi66rE",
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "xY_MUB8adEQ"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"PSjn-HSKiX6orvNhGZvglLI2lvk/rRRgwge6ptZxyMRs-RzsvEFU6qs\"",
   "id": "PLDWb5NF1kx1qB7HgQ2tJKvAI1eXgw8QWwXeA8Anwu4VY",
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "xcc9S_ik0v8"
   }
  }
...
```

Then you have the **video IDs** of the playlist.

I look up quickly the github you link into in your post, you would have something like this :
( /!\ I haven't tested this code/!)

```
use Madcoda\Youtube;

$youtube = new Youtube(array('key' => '/* Your API key here */'));

// Set Default Parameters
$params = array(
    'part'          => 'contentDetails',
);

$playlistItems = $youtube->getPlaylistItemsByPlaylistId('PL590L5WQmH8fJ54F369BLDSqIwcs-TCfs');

print_r($playlistItems);
```

Comment: Great, i did now just test it but i get `undefined index: results`

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student if you don't have the base for coding i can't help you.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: I've found that this does not seem to work with the PHP library. A response is sent, but items array is blank.